# How to multiple Header in ag grid angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want **ag grid using angular 11** like below table.
this how can i do so?
Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

|  | Header 1 | Header 1 | Header 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Header 2** | **Header 2** | **Header 2** |
|  | **Header 3** | **Header 3** | **Header 3** |
| One | Two | Three | Four |

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: thanks a lot to try to help me! i have solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it.
Here is solution the code and result image what i want to get.
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u2Ka.png)

Here is plunker Link :   https://plnkr.co/edit/tHltspkYGhvOWSuB

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div class="example-wrapper">
    <ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-alpine"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;

  private columnDefs;
  private defaultColDef;
  private rowData: [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Athlete1',
        children : [
          {
            headerName: 'Athlete2',
            children : [
              {
                headerName: 'Athlete3',
                field: 'athlete',
                width: 150,
                suppressSizeToFit: true,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      sortable: true,
      resizable: true,
    };
  }
```

thanks a lot for try to help me!